# Why are my textures on a sculpted plane so blocky and how can I fix it?

Tags: texturing, sculpting

I added a plane and then sculpted it, but when I went to add a texture it turned out all blocky and distorted. I've tried with many different textures and all of them do this. I'm new to blender so does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots: please don't steal my text :D ...and i wonder...why doesn't ctrl-t help here, if it is plugged in UV? and maybe apply scale?

Comment: hey I was first on share your file! you only arrived one year and a half ago

Comment: Looks like inverted normals. SHIFT N with everything selected in edit mode